# Can i play mpeg files in linux

Tags: linux, firefox, html, mpeg

I am trying to play video in browser. I use 'embed' tag in HTML.

The problem is, i am trying with a browser in linux, but i dont have the plugin installed in the browser(firefox). When i click ' install missing plugins', it says error saying unable to install.

Is it because mpeg file can't be played in linux? Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is because there isn't a suitable plugin in the browser's database of known plugins. I believe VideoLan Client has a plugin that could cope with it.

If you want to do video on the web, then you are generally best off either simply going down the Flash route, or providing the video in WebM and h.264 and using the `<video>` element (usually with Flash as a backup for older versions of IE). This has the added benefit of being much more bandwidth efficient than MPEG 1 video.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options, mplayer or xine... I prefer mplayer.. go to

http://www.mplayerhq.hu/homepage/design6/dload.html and download one of the source files...

To install:

1)go to your CLI (Command Line Interface) which should be konsole, xterm or something like that

2)go to the directory using this syntax | cd  | cd .. (goto previous directory) and use the command ls to view whats in your current directory.

3)type tar -zxvf "filename"

4)it will create a folder, cd into that folder

5)type ./configure

6)type make

7)type su and enter password for r00t

8)type make install

now in the command line, there should be a command mplayer, have fun!